# Skype for business - Get Presence & user Image details in Angular 5

Tags: c#, angular, skype-for-business

I am building a web app where I need to show user's Skype for business presence status and image.

Please suggest the way to achieve this in Angular 5 or c#.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Check this--- https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/GettingStarted which provides the information to integrate Skype to your application. For Angular5 either, you can check if typings is available or define the variable as any to use in type script code.

Comment: Id like to know this as well. What if you are behind a proxy and cannot connect to the sdkbootstrap